# jQuery Autocomplete: CSS ui-focus-state class not added to focused item when using key arrows

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Normally, when using jQuery Autocomplete, one can browse through the shown list items with keys. If the item currently chosen with arrow keys is to be styled with CSS, I do this:

```
.ui-state-focus {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

This worked for me every time.

Currently, in jQuery UI - v1.12.0, the `ui-state-focus` class is not added to the list element when it's selected with arrow keys.

I render the items in a **custom** way, like this:

```
return $('<li>')
    .attr('data-id', item.id)
    .attr('tabindex', '-1')
    .append(appendItem) /* Text content of the item */
    .appendTo(ul);
```

I understand this probably has nothing to do with the jQuery UI version I'm using. But I don't get why the `ui-state-focus` is not added to my items, so I can style the focus state.

**UPDATE**

Also, when I use the `autoFocus: true` property in the Autocomplete config - it doesn't work at all. It should focus on the first list element shown, but it does nothing. Changing other properties (like `delay`) works fine.

Answer (score 6):

It actually has to do with the jquery-ui version you are using. They are mentioning the change in the v1.12 upgrade guide.

https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#use-consistent-styling-for-focused-and-active-items

> We used to style active parent menu items with ui-state-active, while everything else got **ui-state-focus** (or ui-state-hover, which we style the same as focus). When a menu item in a submenu has focus, the parent menu item gets ui-state-active, which is inconsistent and confusing. We've now switched **to using only the ui-state-active class**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a sub DOM element inside the li, for example:

```
<li><div class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"></div></li>
```

This wrapper will now get the *ui-state-active* class (in before this class was called *ui-state-focus*) you can style within your CSS, otherwise this state won't be applied to the selected row when the wrapper is missing, which is also a change to previous jQuery UI autocomplete versions.

Comment: I was pulling my hair out over this until i actually added the `ui-menu-item-wrapper` class to the DOM element, which seems to be what Jquery searches for, not just the first child element...

Comment: There is the correct answer regarding v1.12.1 , perfect!

Comment: There is the correct answer regarding v1.12.1 , perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Need to customize js(v1.12) for ui-focus-state class added to focused item when using key arrows

**Custom way like this** :

```
Step 1:
                   focused = this.active.children( ".ui-menu-item-wrapper" );
                   this._addClass( focused, null, "ui-state-active" );
    **Replace with**:
                    focused = this.active.closest( ".ui-menu-item" );
                    this._addClass( focused, null, "ui-state-focus" );

Step 2:
                   activeParent = this.active.parent().closest( ".ui-menu-item" ).
                   children( ".ui-menu-item-rapper" );
                   this._addClass( activeParent, null, "ui-state-active" ); 
    **Replce with**:
                   activeParent = this.active.parent().closest( ".ui-menu-item" );
                   this._addClass( activeParent, null, "ui-state-focus" );

Step 3:           this._removeClass( this.active.children( ".ui-menu-item-wrapper" )
                  ,null, "ui-state-active" );

   **Replace with** :
                  this._removeClass( this.active.closest( ".ui-menu-item" ),
                  null, "ui-state-focus" );
```